# Removing elements of an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to c and was wondering if there are any built in operations to remove a specified element from an array.

for example if I wanted to remove the even elements in an array

```
for(.....) //goes through the array one by one
if(nums[i] / 2 = 0)
   nums[i].remove;
```

What could I put instead of .remove to remove the number.

on a separate note if anybody knows a good documentation website for other c array operations would you be able to link it?

Comment: Hint: It's probably easier to accumulate into a new array. C has no array manipulation functions at all, so you need either a library or to write the code. If you want something less bare-bones you're probably looking for C++ which has the Standard Library and array type containers.

Comment: Is there any way to keep track of what the even numbers are so that I can then create the new array with only the odd numbers?

Comment: If you want to move these in-place in the same array you'll need a way of copying entries from one spot to another, compacting it down and incrementing an "offset" counter each time you detect a removal. Note the array won't change size, the allocation is the same, so if you need to trim it you need to reallocate memory somehow. You may end up writing a lot of code here to emulate dynamic arrays, but that's just how C tends to be at a low level.

Answer (score 4):

No, elements cannot be removed from an array.

An array has a certain size from the moment you create it and that size cannot be changed.

Comment: You can `realloc` it if it's dynamically allocated, but arrays like `int x[10]` are fixed size.

Comment: `realloc` does not change the size of an array -- it (logically) creates a new array and copies the data from the old array before freeing it.  In some cases it *might* be able to reuse the old memory directly (thus avoiding the copy), but you can't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to loop through your array starting at the item you want to remove and then copy each successive array item into the one before it. e.g. Shift the array items to the left.

Once you have done that, you can use `realloc()` to trim the last array item off of the allocated memory. You'll of course need to do the math to determine the size of each array item and pass `realloc()` the original size of the array minus the one that you are going to "trim off".

Other options would be`memmove` and `memcopy`, but then you get into all kinds of extra temp buffers.

**An example of "manually" shifting array items:**

```
int* items = NULL;
int arraySize = 10;
int itemToRemove = 5;

items = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * arraySize);

//Initialize the array with some dummy values.
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    items[i] = (i * 100);
}

//Print out the contents of the array - before we remove an item.
printf("Before removing item:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    printf("items[%d]: %d\n", i, items[i]);
}   

//Shift each array item left, starting at the item specified by "itemToRemove".
for (int i = itemToRemove; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    items[i] = items[i + 1];
}

arraySize--; //Be sure to keep track of the new array size.

//Reallocate the array, this will trim the size of the allocated block of memory.
items = (int*)realloc(items, sizeof(int) * arraySize);

//Print out the contents of the array - after we remove an item.
//** NOTICE: The array now only contains 9 items and the 5th one contains the data previously held in the 6th, etc.
printf("After removing item:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    printf("items[%d]: %d\n", i, items[i]);
}

//Be sure to cleanup when done. :)
free(items);
```

Comment: Detail: `int* items` is a pointer, not an _array_.  Useful for a learner to know the difference and  why they seem similar.